# Can I change Cron launch time when it's processing?

Tags: cron, jobs

I'm new to Cron. I've just made a cron, which imports 8000 products. I've made it to import every hour, but I never want it to process again and to ensure, that it doesn't start again, when it's still goinf. Therefore, I want to change the time to like every week or something. Is this possible, even though the cron job is running?

Sorry for my bad formulation. I hope you understand.

Have a pleasant day.

Comment: Which do you really want - "... never want it to process again ..." (in which case there's no reason for it to be in `cron` to begin with) or "... change the time to like every week ..."? You can't have both.

Comment: I found out. I just changed it. I dont have acces to SSH, so I had to do it through cron. Also since the plugin was tailor-made for cron.